# Can I compile go from source for big-endian arm?

Tags: go, endianness

I know when building go can clarify GOARCH=arm, but how to set it for big-endian. Does it support?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is the one you got from minux on github:

> Just FYI, Go doesn't support big endian ARM.

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11079

<sup>(As of June 5th 2015)</sup>

Edit: The reason is documented [here](https://golang.org/doc/install/source): the ARM architectures supported are all little-endian. Theoretically, you could contribute your own big-endian port but I don't think that will be trivial.

Comment: Could you give a reason? Can I use armeb-linux-gcc to recompile go from source?